# How to show count of each bin on histogram on the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I figured out how to get the count of each bin from ggplot, does anyone know how to show these numbers on the plot?

```
g <- ggplot()+geom_histogram()
ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]]$count
```

Comment: Use `stat_bin` with `geom_text`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about how to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add a `stat_bin` to do the calculations of counts for you, and then use those values for the labels and heights. Here's an example

```
set.seed(15)
dd<-data.frame(x=rnorm(100,5,2))
ggplot(dd, aes(x=x))+ geom_histogram() +
    stat_bin(aes(y=..count.., label=..count..), geom="text", vjust=-.5)
```

[image: labeled histogram]

Comment: what if you only want to show those that are non-zero?

Comment: quick n' dirty way to remove zeroes: aes(y=..count.., label=ifelse(..count..==0,"",..count..)

Comment: Just an update for 2023 readers, using this does still work, but replace each instance of the `..count..` with `after_stat(count)`. 
"The dot-dot notation (`..count..`) was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
i Please use `after_stat(count)` instead."