# Set minor breaks for datetime X-axis, ggplot

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I am using the following code to plot a DateTime column as a histogram for each day.

Even after setting the X-axis breaks to 1 day, I am getting 1 Month probably the default option.  How can I plot the X-axis with "Year-Month-Day" for each day?

Also if possible I want to display the count on top of each bar.

code

```
data <- read.table("input.csv", sep=",", head=T)

data$datetime <- as.Date(data$datetime)

ggplot(data, aes(x=datetime)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, colour="black", fill="white")  + 
  scale_x_date(date_minor_breaks = "1 day")
```

data

```
index,datetime,values,type
55,2019-11-02 12:00:00,2.2571265131358302,x
56,2019-11-02 13:00:00,2.4175854658358227,x
57,2019-11-02 14:00:00,2.7247976096720685,x
58,2019-11-02 15:00:00,3.0477882795726146,x
59,2019-11-02 16:00:00,3.2006008421516996,x
60,2019-11-02 17:00:00,3.2116870146833625,x
61,2019-11-02 18:00:00,3.4693910132468457,x
62,2019-11-02 19:00:00,3.911869748466746,x
63,2019-11-02 20:00:00,4.00069618775975,x
64,2019-11-02 22:00:00,4.0834105399449285,x
65,2019-11-02 23:00:00,4.160321416499418,x
66,2019-11-03 00:00:00,4.098125637510356,x
67,2019-11-03 01:00:00,4.021221769171646,x
68,2019-11-03 02:00:00,4.017759023510684,x
69,2019-11-03 03:00:00,4.013082714411543,x
70,2019-11-03 04:00:00,4.057993925343051,x
71,2019-11-03 05:00:00,4.194095193140784,x
72,2019-11-03 07:00:00,4.294259567020734,x
73,2019-11-03 08:00:00,4.337746909001244,x
74,2019-11-03 09:00:00,4.384365666444803,x
75,2019-11-03 10:00:00,4.448100962130655,x
76,2019-11-03 11:00:00,4.501990074404225,x
77,2019-11-03 13:00:00,4.52830137381731,x
78,2019-11-03 14:00:00,4.647279146289785,x
79,2019-11-03 15:00:00,4.776722797787091,x
80,2019-11-03 19:00:00,4.696071186160853,x
81,2019-11-03 21:00:00,4.57669998620599,x
82,2019-11-03 22:00:00,4.462372935827071,x
83,2019-11-03 23:00:00,4.29887239487861,x
84,2019-11-04 00:00:00,4.138775537444896,x
85,2019-11-04 01:00:00,4.010458288624996,x
86,2019-11-04 02:00:00,3.8001917855220837,x
87,2019-11-04 03:00:00,3.5833796414675563,x
88,2019-11-04 04:00:00,3.4035716671606404,x
89,2019-11-04 05:00:00,3.272242285475774,x
90,2019-11-04 06:00:00,3.103512688095525,x
91,2019-11-04 08:00:00,3.1125352688100882,x
92,2019-11-04 09:00:00,3.220763083848201,x
93,2019-11-04 10:00:00,3.290134157323074,x
94,2019-11-04 11:00:00,3.415488671370309,x
95,2019-11-04 12:00:00,3.5455879768850576,x
96,2019-11-04 13:00:00,3.5474491297923727,x
97,2019-11-04 14:00:00,3.783816611089137,x
98,2019-11-04 15:00:00,4.184648621004391,x
99,2019-11-04 16:00:00,4.2413488810807864,x
100,2019-11-04 18:00:00,4.179690857096466,x
101,2019-11-05 08:00:00,4.186025943693791,x
102,2019-11-05 09:00:00,4.028004946673923,x
103,2019-11-05 12:00:00,3.996324873094708,x
104,2019-11-05 14:00:00,4.170572049548053,x
105,2019-11-05 15:00:00,4.324133816110184,x
106,2019-11-05 16:00:00,4.38233647529367,x
107,2019-11-05 17:00:00,4.375290157364679,x
108,2019-11-05 18:00:00,4.360382781128352,x
109,2019-11-05 19:00:00,4.264913977361403,x
110,2019-11-05 20:00:00,4.1399117448002025,x
111,2019-11-05 21:00:00,4.181169914887134,x
112,2019-11-05 22:00:00,4.251114951814682,x
113,2019-11-06 00:00:00,4.235355868286902,x
114,2019-11-06 01:00:00,4.246615325280132,x
115,2019-11-06 02:00:00,4.2108788354127595,x
116,2019-11-06 03:00:00,4.150994459861172,x
117,2019-11-06 04:00:00,4.053771508278776,x
118,2019-11-06 05:00:00,3.9656677100404196,x
119,2019-11-06 06:00:00,3.891497364440651,x
120,2019-11-06 07:00:00,3.9250961484429268,x
121,2019-11-06 09:00:00,3.9564409947149786,x
122,2019-11-06 10:00:00,3.934135576221536,x
123,2019-11-06 11:00:00,3.811665254552286,x
124,2019-11-06 13:00:00,3.698395441791204,x
125,2019-11-06 14:00:00,3.6541064673462826,x
126,2019-11-06 15:00:00,3.594042699299084,x
127,2019-11-06 16:00:00,3.450994105235735,x
128,2019-11-06 17:00:00,3.3646913567819343,x
129,2019-11-06 18:00:00,3.2999220715176176,x
130,2019-11-06 19:00:00,3.258550773145985,x
131,2019-11-06 21:00:00,3.2225326106631136,x
132,2019-11-06 22:00:00,3.185935446208913,x
133,2019-11-06 23:00:00,3.1472600656989873,x
134,2019-11-07 00:00:00,3.096357252528618,x
135,2019-11-07 01:00:00,3.0201448403174727,x
136,2019-11-07 02:00:00,3.019167468392874,x
137,2019-11-07 03:00:00,3.065834385577178,x
138,2019-11-07 05:00:00,3.111118977817557,x
139,2019-11-07 06:00:00,2.997443808096788,x
140,2019-11-07 07:00:00,2.9863646062096496,x
141,2019-11-07 08:00:00,2.9854114565645036,x
142,2019-11-07 09:00:00,2.976881175704244,x
143,2019-11-07 10:00:00,2.9485472925204563,x
144,2019-11-07 11:00:00,2.9052588427934265,x
145,2019-11-07 12:00:00,2.8723489707552354,x
146,2019-11-07 13:00:00,2.787288523493735,x
147,2019-11-07 14:00:00,2.699838153360574,x
148,2019-11-07 15:00:00,2.7790335378861903,x
149,2019-11-07 16:00:00,2.7701168032009678,x
150,2019-11-07 17:00:00,2.7599015900121775,x
151,2019-11-07 18:00:00,2.734276786826625,x
152,2019-11-07 19:00:00,2.6166425495004892,x
153,2019-11-07 20:00:00,2.480661023265874,x
154,2019-11-08 01:00:00,2.3245284179813024,x
155,2019-11-08 02:00:00,2.1160992644464174,x
156,2019-11-08 03:00:00,2.0041605300101835,x
157,2019-11-08 04:00:00,1.8515859873500127,x
598,2019-12-29 22:00:00,1.6110582697766904,x
599,2019-12-29 23:00:00,1.6596777339084172,x
600,2019-12-30 00:00:00,1.6872956896946691,x
601,2019-12-30 01:00:00,1.681427364032406,x
602,2019-12-30 02:00:00,1.6646005456192854,x
603,2019-12-30 03:00:00,1.61024577041883,x
787,2020-01-12 20:00:00,1.432215548619208,x
788,2020-01-12 21:00:00,1.482798113602255,x
789,2020-01-12 22:00:00,1.5180138321075316,x
790,2020-01-12 23:00:00,1.5862635616643168,x
791,2020-01-13 00:00:00,1.624179322341154,x
792,2020-01-13 01:00:00,1.5897191079933364,x
793,2020-01-13 02:00:00,1.5686478770443524,x
794,2020-01-13 03:00:00,1.5158600949449366,x
795,2020-01-13 04:00:00,1.4760764670728665,x
796,2020-01-13 05:00:00,1.4869610695066484,x
797,2020-01-13 07:00:00,1.5493409766366932,x
798,2020-01-13 08:00:00,1.6101944516836666,x
799,2020-01-13 09:00:00,1.6237659716487467,x
800,2020-01-13 10:00:00,1.6041134677825444,x
801,2020-01-13 11:00:00,1.5903269214934665,x
802,2020-01-13 13:00:00,1.536524696499736,x
803,2020-01-13 14:00:00,1.494193483950321,x
804,2020-01-13 15:00:00,1.4816960437129962,x
805,2020-01-13 16:00:00,1.5132917235386587,x
806,2020-01-13 18:00:00,1.6435825530166581,x
807,2020-01-13 19:00:00,1.8375058361044376,x
808,2020-01-13 20:00:00,1.9585768838462818,x
809,2020-01-13 21:00:00,1.9788951029564366,x
810,2020-01-13 22:00:00,1.9860829813291714,x
811,2020-01-13 23:00:00,1.9216810837736404,x
812,2020-01-14 00:00:00,1.86184574914949,x
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original code was working as intended, which is to say that `scale_x_date(date_minor_breaks = '1 day')` was setting the *minor breaks* in your x axis to be separated by day.  Minor breaks are not labeled, whereas Major breaks are labeled.  So you had an axis that was separated by month (major breaks) and then you had all the minor axis tick marks for each day.

To label by each day, you need to set `date_breaks="1 day"` within `scale_x_date()`, and then specify the format of the label to be YYYY-MM-DD via specifying `date_labels=`.

If we do this with you code you get the following icky mess:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=datetime)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, colour="black", fill="white")  +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

[image]

If you want to label every day, you need to make those labels fit.  In which case, you can do that by formatting the theme for the axis text to be rotated.  `vjust=0.5` is necessary if you do that, since the default does not align your text in the middle vertically.

For adding counts above each histogram bar, [this has been answered already here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768546/how-to-show-count-of-each-bin-on-histogram-on-the-plot).  Your case is a bit different though, because you have a lot of values that would read "0".  It would be much better to show only those labels where the count was > 0.  For this, I'm just building into the `aes(label=` call an `ifelse()` function to represent the label as blank when it is equal to 0.  This doesn't mean the label is not there... it just means it contains "NA".

You will also notice the `y` aesthetic for `stat_bin` is set to be `..count..+1`.  This ensures that each value is drawn just above each bar, rather than right on the edge of the bar.  You could also mess with `vjust` to get this to work right.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=datetime)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, colour="black", fill="white")  +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..count..+1,
    label=ifelse(..count..!=0, ..count.., NA)), geom='text', binwidth = 0.5) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = '%Y-%m-%d') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, size=7, vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

I personally think the plot could look a bit better, and I think it's still hard to read with the label every day.  So here's my suggestion to snazz it up a bit.  In the code below, I switch to the `theme_bw()` (preference), then format your major axis ticks to be every week, with minor ticks every 1 day.  I also prefer to have bar graphs (like histograms) to have the bottom of the bar meet the x axis, so use `scale_y_continuous(expand=`) to do that.  Finally, I formatted the axis label to include a line break and removed the rotation.  Not sure if it fits your preference, but it also shows you a bit more of what you can do when combining `date_breaks=` and `date_minor_breaks=` in the same plot.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=datetime)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, colour="black", fill="white")  +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..count..+1,
    label=ifelse(..count..!=0, ..count.., NA)), geom='text', binwidth = 0.5) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_minor_breaks = '1 day', date_labels = '%Y\n%m-%d') +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=expansion(mult=c(0,0.05)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is super useful. Is it possible to set `date_minor_breaks` to 12 hours?

Comment: Certainly possible, but you need: (1) `date$datetime` needs to be in `POSIXct` format so that it includes "time", (2) use `scale_x_datetime` in place of `scale_x_date`, and (3)... probably play around with the bins/binwidth so that the stat function does not complain.  If your binwidth=1, that means it's one unit of POSIXct time... so 1 second!  Too many bins, which is why you need to change if you go that route.